# Libgdx sprite depths are different on android than it is on Desktop

Tags: java, android, opengl-es, libgdx

I've been having a weird problem with the game I am developing. So I created a render method where sprites get drawn in a certain order to create a sense of depth. if that makes sense. So background tiles get rendered first, then there is map features that get drawn after the background tiles so they appear above the background tiles. Now the problem is, this system works just fine on my desktop and I get the desired behavior. However, on my android device or any android simulators, the order of which the sprites are drawn seems to be ignored. The map features that I draw after the background tiles don't show because they get blocked by the background tiles even though they get drawn after the tiles. I noticed this when a small portion of a "TREE" sprite showed on the edge of the map because it wasn't fully blocked by the background tiles. I'll upload images to demonstrate.

This is how it looks on my desktop. Perfectly fine. Mapfeatures do get drawn on-top of the background tiles and there are no problems. I tested my depth methodology to see if I am implementing it wrong and no. All tests work fine on my desktop. I can successfully render sprites on different depths.

[image: DESKTOP]
And this is how it looks on an android device/emulator. Exact same code. Please notice the tree that is popping out of the edge of the screen. The bottom part of it is blocked by tiles. So only the upper part of it is rendered. I tried to use a semi transparent texture for the tiles. And I was able to see all map features. So I know the textures are loaded just fine and the problem is somewhere else. I don't think it's a code issue either since it works just fine on my desktop.

[image]

Does anyone have any ideas or experienced anything similar?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So I figured it out. I had collected the each depth in a hashmap and used the depth (integer) as a key and iterated through it using a for loop that iterates through it's keyset. This way i didnt have direct control over the order of iteration. The order of which the keyset is being iterated differed on my desktop. The android environment followed a different iteration so the depths were not rendered in the order I wished. I used  a list instead and iterated through it using an order I desired to. It worked.